# Convert String to Lambda Expression Against Collection

Tags: c#, lambda

How can I convert a string representation of a property selector, against a collection, into a lambda expression?

The input is formatted as:

```
"Child.Name"
```

I need to convert this into a predicate to be used in an OrderBy clause;

```
query.OrderBy(x => x.Child.FirstOrDefault().Name);
```

Is it possible to also have a solution that works if the property is not a collection, to work against a standard property or field, for example;

```
"Quantity"
```

would create a predicate such as;

```
x => x.Quantity
```

EDIT:

Just to attempt to reword the above question, if I can alter the input string, is it possible to execute;

```
"Child.FirstOrDefault().Name"
```

as

```
x => x.Child.FirstOrDefault().Name
```

within an OrderBy ?

Comment: You probably should investigate [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)

Comment: What's the type of 'Child' object?

Comment: What do you mean by *"I need to convert this into a predicate"*? Do you already have an object with a `Child` collection property?

Comment: @MGG_Soft Child is a collection of class objects.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov query is an IQueryable of objects, each contains a property called Child which holds a collection of class objects.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will first need to get an instance of the class by name using the [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) types:

```
var child = System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Assembly", "Child"));
```

Then you can get the property by name with [GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var childType = (typeof)child;
var name = childType.GetProperty("Name");
```

Then you can pass these types to your query.

Alternatively, you can use [the LINQ Predicate Builder library](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

Comment: Why going through the hoops of instantiating the object, just to get the type? `var childType = Type.GetType("NAMESPACE.Child, ASSEMBLY_NAME");`

Answer (score 0):

There is an application that resolves your question. Try it and tell me something.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Punto de entrada principal para la aplicación.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            List<Parent> Parents = new List<Parent>();
            List<Parent> orderedParents = Parents.Cast<Parent>().OrderBy(x => x.Cast<Child>().Select(y => y.myName)).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Parent: IQueryable 
    {
        List<Child> child = new List<Child>();

        #region Miembros de IQueryable

        public Type ElementType
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public System.Linq.Expressions.Expression Expression
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public IQueryProvider Provider
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Miembros de IEnumerable

        public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class Child: Parent 
    {
        public string myName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will return the string value of a property on a collection:

```
string propertyValue = source.GetType()
                .GetProperty(stringProperty)
                .GetValue(query.FirstOrDefault(), null) as string;
```

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: John Saunders - What do you mean?

Comment: You have not answered the question. What you wrote would have been a good comment.

Comment: Ah, okay. I reworded it to imply an answer as opposed to a question.